# Real time application with Brunch, Node.js, Socket.io, MySQL, Rails and Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ember.js, socket.io, brunch

I'm trying to use Brunch with Rails and Ember.js with Separation of Frontend and Backend then use Node.js and Socket.io for real time updates.

I think this tutorial [Adding Real-Time to Rails With Socket.IO, Node.js and Backbone.js](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/25/adding_real-time_to_rails_with_socket.IO_nodejs_and_backbonejs_with_demo/)

is useful and explains how Rails, Socket.io, Node.js and Backbone.js can be implemented but how would we go about adding Brunch and Ember.js with database integration?

Do we have any suggestions? or are there good tutorial/example out there that we could make use of?

Comment: I've marked to close this; as written you're asking for links to tutorials or similar, which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I couldn't find a tutorial for this online hence why I am asking what some expert developers would do in using something similar to above technologies. In saying that, some questions ask recommended tutorials on StackOverflow gaining more than 200 votes! http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tutorial do they need to be closed aswell?

Comment: While you may find some examples, many more are closed.